# Getting a length mismatch error on this code, what does it mean?

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot a time series analysis chart and I am getting an error that says "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 50 elements, new values have 1 elements". What does it mean? I'll include my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def init_data_visualisation():
    df = pd.read_csv('MasterFile.csv', index_col=0)
    df.index.name=None
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
    df.index.name=None
    df.columns = ['Robbery']
    df['Robbery'] = df.Robbery.apply(lambda x: int(x) *100)
    df.Robbery.plot(title='Robbery Over 18 Months', fontsize=14)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_data_visualisation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 50 elements, new values have 1 elements"
```

It basically means that in the data frame you have 50 columns, but you are trying to rename them with 1 column.

try this link if you need a more clear understanding:
https://joshuaotwell.com/renaming-pandas-dataframe-columns-with-examples/